# How to return Observable not specifing type?

Tags: angular

I do HTTP request to server using Observer:

```
public getNewStudyYearForm(schoolId: number, studyPeriodId: number): Observable<Current> {}
```

How to return Observable response not specifing type `<Current>`? Because I dont want to create model `Current`;

Is it: `Observable<any>`?

Comment: Yep. any sounds correct

Comment: You can use public getNewStudyYearForm(schoolId: number, studyPeriodId: number): any{}

Comment: Can I use Promise in this case? For Http request?

Comment: For an http you can use promise and observable.

Comment: Can you share one sample or external link where is descibed promises in http requests?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Thanks, but I have not found there description how to use chain of promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is

```
:Observable<any>
```